# Android currently index from the arrayList try to update

Tags: java, android, updates

```
ArrayList < Titles > atitlename;
ArrayList < Items > aitems;

static int currentListIndex = 0, currentItemIndex = 0;

public void onClick(View button)
    {

switch (button.getId())

        case R.id.button_update: {

        int id = aitems.get(currentListIndex).getItemId();
        String newContent = etupdateName.getText().toString();
        etupdateName.setText("");
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DBManager.C_ITEM_NAME, newContent);

        try {
            database = manager.getWritableDatabase();
            database.update(DBManager.TABLE_ITEMS, values, DBManager.C_ID + "=" + id, null);

            Toast.makeText(this, "you saved: " + newContent, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            database.close();
            refreshitem();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error" + e);
            Toast.makeText(this, "error" + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        break;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView << ? > parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        String name = (aitems.get(position).getItemName());
        etupdateName.setText(name);

    }
```

try to get the currentListindex from the ArrayList to the id, I set the currentListIndex = 0, cause I don't know how to get the current index, I got the int from the OnItemClick because it passes the int Position from the method, But i can't pass the int Position from the Onclick method.
I want the id = whatever I Click the item from the listview.

When I click the Item in the listview where id = 2, and I try to update it, it always updates the item where index = 0(becasue i set the currentItemIndex= 0).

what I want is to update the item's id = whatever I click the item from the listview which I have done it by using the int Position from the OnItemClick method.

Example:
I click the item from the listview where id = 3, it displays the item name in the EditText Box, then I want to update the item name, it will update the item name where id =3.

Comment: Where are you initializing `aitems`?

Comment: ArrayList < Titles > atitlename;
ArrayList < Items > aitems;

Comment: That's a declaration, not initialization.

Comment: public Items(int itemId, int titleId, String itemName)
    {
        this.itemId = itemId;
        this.titleId = titleId;
        this.itemName = itemName;

    }

Comment: Mind posting full class here?